# How do I output this table correctly?

Tags: php, css, archive

This code outputs the image on the left, and what I'm looking for is the image on the right: https://s27.postimg.org/niua66jqr/archive.jpg
How do I output this table correctly? Is it a problem with the archive code or the style code?

```css
.archive-container {
  margin-top: 85px;
}
.archive-container h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.archive,
.year,
th {
  font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #a6a6a6;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.archive:hover th,
.year:hover th {
  color: #a6a6a6 !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
.archive a:link:hover {
  color: #e69900 !important;
}
a:link {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: black;
  /
}
table {
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-spacing: 25px 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="archive-container">

  <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var domainroot = "sitetitle.com"

    function Gsitesearch(curobj) {
      curobj.q.value = "site:" + domainroot + " " + curobj.qfront.value
    }
  </script>


  <form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get" onSubmit="Gsitesearch(this)">

    <p class="search">Search:
      <br />
      <input name="q" type="hidden" class="texta" />
      <input name="qfront" type="text" style="width: 186px; text-size: 12px; height: 14px;" />
    </p>

  </form>


  <table id=arc>
    <?php $query="SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS `year`, MONTH(post_date) as `month`, DAYOFMONTH(post_date) as `dayofmonth`, ID, post_name, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'article' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_date DESC" ; $key=m d5($query);
    $cache=w p_cache_get( 'mp_archives' , 'general'); if ( !isset( $cache[ $key ] ) ) { $arcresults=$ wpdb->get_results($query); $cache[ $key ] = $arcresults; wp_cache_add( 'mp_archives', $cache, 'general' ); } else { $arcresults = $cache[ $key ]; } if ($arcresults) { $last_year = 0; $last_month = 0; foreach ( $arcresults as $arcresult ) { $year = $arcresult->year;
    $month = $arcresult->month; if ($year != $last_year) { $last_year = $year; $last_month = 0; ?>
    <tr class=year>
      <th>
        <br />
        <br />
        <?php echo $arcresult->year; ?></th>
    </tr>
    <?php } if ($month !=$ last_month) { $last_month=$ month; ?>
    <tr class=archive>
      <th>
        <?php echo $wp_locale->get_month($arcresult->month); ?></th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <tr class=archive>
      <th>
        <?php echo $arcresult->dayofmonth; ?></th>
      <td id=p<?php echo $arcresult->ID; ?>>
        <a href="/<?php echo $arcresult->post_name; ?>">
          <?php echo strip_tags(apply_filters( 'the_title', $arcresult->post_title)); ?></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } } ?>
  </table>
</div>
<!-- /end .container -->
```

Comment: You should provide some of the  HTML that sends your pHp script .... instead the script

Comment: `<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
 <head>
  <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>sitetitle.com</title>
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
 </head>`

Comment: @ GCyrillus - Is this what you're talking about?

Comment: When I remove that, it removes all the styling and it lines up correctly, but I'd still need to change the fonts and header stuff.

Comment: It looks like this (without the `<?php wp_head(); ?>`) https://s24.postimg.org/4tt7nw50l/archive2.png

Comment: Yes , the php is useless to us , look at the source of your page and provide the HTML generated by the script , so we can see the full structure and also see if imbrication is fine or HTML generated broken ;), obviously here your script works fine,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
    <table width="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <div>2017</div>
      <div>Januari</div>
      <div>1</div>
      </td>
      <td>Long title here</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>
      <div>2016</div>
      <div>Januari</div>
      <div>1</div>
      </td>
      <td>Long title here</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```